# How can I display an exit button that closes a JavaFX program?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I've been trying to add a button to this one program in java that says "Quit" and then closes the program. The program that was given makes and shows an image of a rocket, so I can't use an example given to me by another program called `QuitButtonExample.java` as each program has something different, and using similar structure in `QuitButtonExample` in `Rocket.java` only allows me to show either the rocket image or the quit button, if I remove two parts of the code I have. Below is the `Rocket.java` program normally for reference.

Rocket.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Rocket extends Application
{
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Displays a rocket lifting off. The rocket and hatch are polygons
   //  and the flame is a polyline.
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   public void start(Stage primaryStage)
   {
   double[] hullPoints = {200, 25, 240, 60, 240, 230, 270, 260, 
            270, 300, 140, 300, 140, 260, 160, 230, 160, 60};
      Polygon rocket = new Polygon(hullPoints);
      rocket.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
      double[] hatchPoints = {185, 70, 215, 70, 220, 120, 180, 120};

      Polygon hatch = new Polygon(hatchPoints);
      hatch.setFill(Color.MAROON);

      double[] flamePoints = {142, 310, 142, 330, 150, 325, 155, 380, 
               165, 340, 175, 360, 190, 350, 200, 375, 215, 330, 220, 360, 
               225, 355, 230, 370, 240, 340, 255, 370, 260, 335, 268, 340, 
               268, 310};

      Polyline flame = new Polyline(flamePoints);
      flame.setStroke(Color.RED);
      flame.setStrokeWidth(3);

      Group root = new Group(rocket, hatch, flame);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);

      primaryStage.setTitle("Rocket");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }
}
```

I used some code from the `QuitButtonExample.java` program and messed around with it a bit in my `Rocket.java` program, but it gives me an error saying that the program could be simplified. I don't want it to be simplified, and I just want to find a way for both the rocket image and the quit button to display, with the quit button working when pressed to close the program. I've been at this for some time and I'm generally unsure of what to do. I would like some tips to help me understand where to go from here. Below I will post the code of what I have tried.

Rocket1.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Rocket extends Application
{
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Displays a rocket lifting off. The rocket and hatch are polygons
   //  and the flame is a polyline.
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
   public void start(Stage primaryStage)
   {
   double[] hullPoints = {200, 25, 240, 60, 240, 230, 270, 260, 
            270, 300, 140, 300, 140, 260, 160, 230, 160, 60};
      Polygon rocket = new Polygon(hullPoints);
      rocket.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
      double[] hatchPoints = {185, 70, 215, 70, 220, 120, 180, 120};

      Polygon hatch = new Polygon(hatchPoints);
      hatch.setFill(Color.MAROON);

      double[] flamePoints = {142, 310, 142, 330, 150, 325, 155, 380, 
               165, 340, 175, 360, 190, 350, 200, 375, 215, 330, 220, 360, 
               225, 355, 230, 370, 240, 340, 255, 370, 260, 335, 268, 340, 
               268, 310};

      Polyline flame = new Polyline(flamePoints);
      flame.setStroke(Color.RED);
      flame.setStrokeWidth(3);

      Group root = new Group(rocket, hatch, flame);
      
      Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Quit");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            Platform.exit();
        });

        HBox exitButton = new HBox();
        exitButton.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        exitButton.getChildren().add(btn);
            
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, exitButton, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);

      primaryStage.setTitle("Rocket");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show(); 

   }
}
```

Comment: Calling `Platform::exit` in the button's on-action handler is, in the simplest cases, all you need to do. You seem to be doing that, so what is the actual problem?

Comment: *"it gives me an error saying that the program could be simplified"* What does this actually mean? That doesn't sound like any kind of error I've seen. *What* gives you that error (the compiler? the runtime?)? What, exactly, does the error message say?

Comment: *"I just want to find a way for both the rocket image and the quit button to display"* Just put both of them in some kind of layout pane. The choice of layout pane depends on how you want them laid out relative to each other.

Comment: In your second code block: `Scene scene = new Scene(root, exitButton, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);`. I don't think this even compiles.

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading. You know how to do what the title asks (you know how to make an exit button that closes the program): you say so in the question itself. It seems that the question is really asking how you add a button to an existing layout. The title should reflect that.

Comment: Sayori: I have edited your question to address @James_D's point; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this helper method of mine and execute it with your button:

```
public static void displayExitProgramDialog(
        String dialogTitle,
        String contentText) {

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle(dialogTitle);
    alert.setContentText(contentText);
    alert.showAndWait();
    if (alert.getResult().getButtonData() == ButtonData.OK_DONE) {
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only reservation I have about this answer is the use of `System.exit(0)`. If there are no non-daemon threads running after the FX thread terminates then calling that method is unnecessary. And if there _are_ other non-daemon threads running, it would probably be better to start a graceful shutdown from the `Application::stop` method, perhaps calling `System::exit` with a non-zero argument if something goes wrong. Unless maybe you're using shutdown hooks to clean up such things?

Answer (score 3):

Your button handler works; but you appear to be adding the button to a `Pane`, while never adding that `Pane` to the `Parent` passed to your `Scene`. The variation below adds the button to the `HBox`; and it *then* adds the `HBox` to the `Group` named `root`, which  then becomes the root of the [*Scene Graph*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106328).

[image: Rocket]

Scene graph, traversed like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21176630/230513) and elided for clarity:

```
Group@56d9b476[styleClass=root]
  Polygon[…]
  Polygon[[…]
  Polyline[…]
  HBox@25afbfbc
    Button@36457869[…]'Quit'
      Text[text="Quit", x=0.0, y=0.0, …]
```

As tested:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Rocket extends Application {
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Displays a rocket lifting off. The rocket and hatch are polygons
    //  and the flame is a polyline.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        double[] hullPoints = {200, 25, 240, 60, 240, 230, 270, 260,
            270, 300, 140, 300, 140, 260, 160, 230, 160, 60};
        Polygon rocket = new Polygon(hullPoints);
        rocket.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
        double[] hatchPoints = {185, 70, 215, 70, 220, 120, 180, 120};

        Polygon hatch = new Polygon(hatchPoints);
        hatch.setFill(Color.MAROON);

        double[] flamePoints = {142, 310, 142, 330, 150, 325, 155, 380,
            165, 340, 175, 360, 190, 350, 200, 375, 215, 330, 220, 360,
            225, 355, 230, 370, 240, 340, 255, 370, 260, 335, 268, 340,
            268, 310};

        Polyline flame = new Polyline(flamePoints);
        flame.setStroke(Color.RED);
        flame.setStrokeWidth(3);

        Group root = new Group(rocket, hatch, flame);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Quit");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            Platform.exit();
        });

        HBox exitButton = new HBox(btn);
        exitButton.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        root.getChildren().add(exitButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Rocket");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```